# gcc -O3 flag causes warnings that -O2 doesn't

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm building a fairly complex application, which built without any errors/warnings with `-O0`. However when I tried `-O3`, I got a couple of them which are puzzling. For example:

```
1: static pinfo_t* pinfo[2] = { &gv1, &gv2 }; // GLOBAL
2: 
3: int i;
4: int x = sizeof(pinfo);
5: 
6: for (i = 0; i < x; i ++)
7:    if (pinfo[i]->id == NO_ID)
8:        printf("%s\n", pinfo[i]->name);
```

Note the compiler (gcc v4.3.2) built this successfully with `-O0` (with O1 and O2 also). But with `-O3`, the compiler correctly pinpoints line 7 to be a potential problem causing line with the error:

```
error: array subscript is above array bounds
```

Fair enough, but when I comment out line 7, it has no problem with line 8, which should also have been flagged!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Over anonymized. If I assume while = for, I see code that shouldn't raise the error.

Comment: Your while loop is incorrect. A good way to understand what is going on would be to look at the generated assembly for your while loop.

Comment: @Joshua I see a loop that accesses `2 * sizeof(pinfo_t *)` elements of `pinfo`. `sizeof(pinfo_t *)` is more than 1 on all major (and many minor) platforms, so it'd go out of bounds.

Comment: As written, your question has A LOT of problems. The subject says `-O2` but in the body you say `-O0`. Then you ask about commenting out line 6. What is the real situation you're experiencing and what do you want to know about it?

Comment: @Étienne: Yes, it also seems to be fake code...

Comment: Uhm... I very much doubt your "fairly complex application" was "built without any errors/warnings" if it contains the above code.

Comment: Sorry for all the errors; I've been pulling my hairs out over this problem. As I said, the app is fairly complex and I tried to simplify it as much as I can! There are no errors/warnings with any of -O0, -O1 and -O2. The errors occur specifically with -O3.

Comment: @R.. In order to examine the strange appearance of the error, I tried to re-compile the program with line 7 commented out. And this time it didn't throw any errors. That's what I meant.

Comment: Sorry. Been too long since I did sizeof(array).

Comment: You can use the -c switch in gcc and look at the object files's assembly to check which optimization gcc is doing.

Answer (score 8):

Wrt the warnings and optimization level, in GCC some warnings are generated when analyzing the code during optimization passes, and thus when those passes are not enabled, those warnings are not emitted either. It's a long-standing issue, but so far it hasn't propagated high enough on anyone's TODO list.

Comment: Yikes, so if I want fast compilation (`-O0`) then I don't get all the warnings ... well that's good to know.  I sure hope that `-O2` turns on all the warnings because I never compile with `-O3` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Dollars to donuts that the compiler completely unrolls the loop at **-O3** to something like:

```
...

if (pinfo[0]->id == NO_ID)
    printf("%s\n", pinfo[0]->name);
if (pinfo[1]->id == NO_ID)
    printf("%s\n", pinfo[1]->name);
if (pinfo[2]->id == NO_ID)
    printf("%s\n", pinfo[2]->name);

...
```

It then observes that the generated index is out of bounds and warns you about it.

Comment: That makes sense, except there is no error when the 'if' is commented out.

Comment: That doesn't really say much. Who knows what optimizations the compiler is doing and how it treats the `pinfo[i]` inside the `if` statement?

Comment: Ah, perhaps. Seems like I'll have to be spending quite a while fixing code :/